# How to call a MSSQL stored procedure and retrieve output params in PHP using ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to call a MSSQL stored procedure from PHP using ODBC and I guess it is fairly working. I mean, the procedure gets invoked. I get no error. But I am having some trouble retrieving output params.

The procedure does not return anything, but it has one output parameter, which is a `varchar` and I need to get this data.

Here is the code in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcName] 
    @peCodFact varchar(max) = NULL, 
    @peCodsAlmcs varchar(max) = NULL, 
    @peFechaConfDesde date = NULL, 
    @peFechaConfHasta date = NULL, 
    @peCodMed varchar(50) = NULL, 
    @psRegEjec varchar(max) = '<>' OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN TRY
    /* data processing where @psRegEjec is set */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;
```

All the input params can be null, and the param I need to retrieve is `@psRegEjec`.

Here's the code in PHP:

```
$idCon = odbc_connect($dns, $user, $passwd);
if (empty($idCon))
    throw new Exception(odbc_errormsg());

$query = 'DECLARE @psRegEjec varchar(max); ';
$query .= 'EXEC BDName.dbo.ProcName @psRegEjec = @psRegEjec OUTPUT; ';
$query .= 'SELECT @psRegEjec AS data; ';

$res = odbc_exec($idCon, $query);
$datosRes = @odbc_fetch_array($res);
```

I've tried to retrieve the results with `odbc_fetch_object`, `odbc_fetch_array`, and all get the same. The results I'm getting is something like ...

> \x0ø\x14\x7cen\x0)\x0\x0\x0\x11\x0\x0\x0Hø\x11\x7ado_nm_grupo_gestion\x0\xEÔ\x0\x18\r\x12\x7)\x0\x0\x0)\x0\x0\x0˜ø\x11\x7ccion_co_descripcion\x0\xF\x12\x7è\x11\x12\x7)\x0\x0\x0)\x0\x0\x0
>   ø\x11\x7ado_nm_funcionalidad\x0\xEÔ\x0P\x16\x12\x7)\x0\x0\x0)\x0\x0\x0 ù\x11\x7orporacion_descripcion\x0\x7
>   \x1B\x12\x7)\x0\x0\x0)\x0\x0\x0pø\x11\x7raseña
>   anterior\x0\x0ˆ\x1F\x12\x7\x19\x0\x0\x0)\x0\x0\x0hú\x11\x7ripcion\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0y\x0\x0\x0\x19\x0\x0\x0\xF\x1.

and it goes on, pretty large...
So I really don't know what to do. I saw in some article, that is required to create a second procedure, to return the output param from the first one, as ODBC driver does not support procedures output params ...

Is that really so? Is there any other way?

Comment: What is your connection string (`$dns`)?

Comment: here is ... 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=' . $server_ip . ';Database=' . $db_name . ';client_charset=UTF-8;'

Comment: @Zhorov means that are you connected with server or still not?

Comment: yes, I am... the problem is not to connect to db, nor to execute the procedure, but to retrieve the output param

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert the value of your output parameter as `nvarchar(max)`. If your stored procedure executes SELECT statement, then you'll have multiple result sets. Next is working example:

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcNameODBC] 
    @peCodFact varchar(max) = NULL, 
    @peCodsAlmcs varchar(max) = NULL, 
    @peFechaConfDesde date = NULL, 
    @peFechaConfHasta date = NULL, 
    @peCodMed varchar(50) = NULL, 
    @psRegEjec varchar(max) = '<>' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRY
    -- Your actual result set
    SELECT [Column] AS [Result] FROM [Table]
    -- Output parameter
    SET @psRegEjec = 'Value for the output parameter'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, 
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, 
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, 
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, 
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;
```

PHP:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php
    $sql_server   = "server\instance,port";
    $sql_user     = "uid";
    $sql_password = "pwd";
    $sql_database = "database";
    $sql_conn_string = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server='.$sql_server.';Database='.$sql_database.';';
    if ($sql_conn = odbc_connect($sql_conn_string, $sql_user, $sql_password)) {
        $sql = "EXEC ProcNameODBC";

        $sql = 'DECLARE @psRegEjec varchar(max); ';
        $sql .= 'EXEC ProcNameODBC @psRegEjec = @psRegEjec OUTPUT; ';
        $sql .= 'SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @psRegEjec) AS [Result]; ';
        #$sql .= 'SELECT @psRegEjec AS [Result]; ';

        # Result set from stored procedure
        $result = odbc_exec($sql_conn, $sql);
        while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
            $value = odbc_result($result, "Result");
            echo $value.'</br>';
        }

        # SELECT output parameter
        odbc_next_result($result);
        while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
            $value = odbc_result($result, "Result");
            echo $value.'</br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Notes:

Consider using [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). This driver fully supports input and output parameters for stored procedures.

Comment: no, I'm sorry ... I've tried, and I'm still getting garbage data from the DB ...
for that specific example, it returns this ...

"\x0/ê\x5\x0.ê\x5\x11\x0\x0\x0\x11\x0\x0\x0sql\x0˜.ê\x51\x0\x0\x0\x11\x0"

Comment: The driver I'm using is _SQL Server Native Client 10.0_, and you used _SQL Server Native Client 11.0_ ... I tried using that one and it returned this error ..
**Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes) in D:\AppServ\www\test.php on line 20**

Comment: And the problem about using PHP Driver for SQL, is that the project I'm working in, uses ODBC for accessing SQL, so it's kind of a requirement ... :(

Comment: @IvanMtnzVigil Check updated answer. Sorry, but it's tested with _SQL Server Native Client 11.0_. The main point here are multiple result sets.